# DirectShow AviMux grayscale MJPEG

Tags: windows, video, directshow, mjpeg

I wrote a MJPEG compressor DirectShow filter, it works without problems for color images. But when i try to support 8bit greyscale images i'm not able to connect my filter to the Microsoft AVI muxer filter. It will always fail in ReceiveConnection. I basically copy the BITMAPINFOHEADER of the input image and change biCompression to MJPG and reduce biSizeImage.

Does the Microsoft AVI Muxer has any requirements for it's allocator? I use the size of the output BITMAPINFOHEADER and don't care for prefix or alignment currently.

Thei BITMAPINFOHEADER looks as follows:
    biSize 1064
    biWidth 640 
    biHeight -480 
    biPlanes 1 
    biBitCount 8
    biCompression 1196444237 
    biSizeImage 184320 
    biXPelsPerMeter 0
    biYPelsPerMeter 0
    biClrUsed 0
    biClrImportant 0

Changing the height to a positive value has no effect. The biSize is bigger than normal as we use the header so save additional information for the encoding. In color mode we have the same BITMAPINFOHEADER except of the biBitCount beeing 24.

Comment: Why don't you include the full printout of the media type and `VIDEOINFOHEADER` here in your question? The way you see it in debugger as late as possible before the error comes up.

Comment: Cause there is not much interesting to see expcept the size of the image.
  biSize 1064
  biWidth 640
  biHeight -480
  biPlanes 1
  biBitCount 8
  biCompression 1196444237
  biSizeImage 184320
  biXPelsPerMeter 0
  biYPelsPerMeter 0
  biClrUsed 0
  biClrImportant 0

Comment: The quoted `VIDEOINFOHEADER` does not not look valid for MJPG.

Comment: What looks wrong? The only change to the working color mode is the bit count

Answer (score 0):

AVI Mux filter is rejecting media types which are ill-formed. Even though it is not the only possible cause, in this case it looks the most probable (the question really lacks detail).

To find out a valid sample media type, one should build a filter graph that renders into a valid playable MJPG AVI file, such as with the help of [GraphStudioNext](https://github.com/cplussharp/graph-studio-next), and review the media type fields with care.

[image]

The bits of data attached to the original question suggest that at the very least `biSize` and `biHeight` need a fix.

Comment: I tried swapping the height, but it had no effect. The biSize is correct as we attach custom bit to the bitmapinfoheader. We do the same thing for the color mode, and it works without problems.

Comment: I'm trying the connection using graphstudionext and it does not reveal any more information than the debugger

Comment: You did not post full structure you have. You did not post the respective color strcture values that works for you. biSize value is incorrect (see MSDN). biHeight is incorrect. You might have other incorrect values too. AVI Mux stumbles on one of the multiple problems you have (it might ignore other though, meaning that an obvious problem might still be okay for this particular filter).

Comment: biHeight might be negativ to indicate a flip of the height.  When i use an absolute height, DirectShow inserts the Decoder right after the Encoder what makes no sense at all. The size can vary, you can have a palette after the BITMAPINFOHEADER or in our case some meta datas for decoding. Those data have to be there and are no problem for RGB images

Comment: Even though it does not work to "correct" biSize and biHeight. DirectShow will use the Decoder after the encoder before pushing the data to the muxer

Comment: This is all wrong. The media type in question here is the one on the input connection of AVI mux. MJPG media type cannot have bottom to top row order. MJPG has no palette. Screenshot above gives you a correct example of attaching extra bytes, which works as opposed to your way of supplying invalid value for biSize. As you do so many things wrong, I don't understand how you still did not edit your question putting all data you can provide for the question.

Comment: Yes the MJPEG does not need this information. But the avi header written by the muxer does need this information. Also in the color mode, MJPEG has no palette. But it works. So why does the avi muxer accept the header in the color mode with just one change?

How does DirectShow think that it is correct to add the decoder between encoder and muxer if i correct the parameters you pointed out?

Comment: When AVI Mux is unable to complete the connection, Filter Graph Manager attempts to connect using other intermediate filters. It runs through the list of registered filters and mounts some of them between the pins you are connecting trying to make the connection on both sides. This is how decoder jumps in, but it is just a background information here and takes away from the problem in first place.